# PyLucene install: "make" not working and "jvm.dll could not be found"

Tags: python, java, windows, pylucene

I'm trying to get PyLucene going on my computer and have followed all of the steps but am getting stuck at the "make" step. I'm working on 64-bit Windows 10 Machine and my version of Python is 3.9.12.

What I've done:

1.) Install [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) and set environments. In this step, I also installed [Java JDK 18](https://jdk.java.net/18/) as per the recommendation in Apache Ant. I set all of the environment variables as instructed for JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME, and added Ant to the path. I checked and verified that these all worked:

[image]

2.) Download [PyLucene 9.1.0](https://dlcdn.apache.org/lucene/pylucene/), extract the tar file, `cd` into the jcc folder and run `python setup.py build`. I changed the `JAVAHOME` in the setup.py file to `JAVA_HOME` to match the variable path name I made in the above step. I also included `JCC_JDK` because I got an error the first time I ran the `setup.py` where it asked for `JCC_JDK`.

[image]

3.) I edited the Makefile and made sure to have [make installed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm). The top part of the make file is:

```
VERSION=9.1.0
LUCENE_VER=9.1.0
PYLUCENE:=$(shell pwd)
LUCENE_SRC=lucene-java-$(LUCENE_VER)
LUCENE=$(LUCENE_SRC)/lucene
PREFIX_PYTHON=C:\Users\mgsci\anaconda3 # this is where my python.exe is located
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)\python.exe
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc --shared
NUM_FILES=16
```

When I ran `make` I got the error:

```
(base) C:\Users\mgsci\Downloads\PyLucene\pylucene-9.1.0>make
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, which icupkg, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
(cd lucene-java-9.1.0; ./gradlew collectRuntimeJars)
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, (cd lucene-java-9.1.0; ./gradlew collectRuntimeJars), ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [lucene] Error 2
```

And when I just ran `python -m jcc` I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mgsci\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\mgsci\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\mgsci\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\mgsci\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jcc-3.12-py3.9-win-amd64.egg\jcc\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    add_jvm_dll_directory_to_path(find_jvm_dll)
  File "C:\Users\mgsci\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jcc-3.12-py3.9-win-amd64.egg\jcc\windows.py", line 104, in add_jvm_dll_directory_to_path
    raise ValueError("jvm.dll could not be found")
ValueError: jvm.dll could not be found
```

I have the `jvm.dll` file. I can see it in the path `jdk-18.0.2\bin\server`. I also copied the jvm.dll file and placed it both in the `jdk-18.0.2` folder and in the `bin` folder for good measure and still got this error.

What part of process did I screw up?

Comment: The issue was on this line - `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, (cd lucene-java-9.1.0; ./gradlew collectRuntimeJars), ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.`. It did not find the specified file.